# Можно ли исправить проблему с добавлением песни в очередь? discord.js 12

Tags: javascript

Так вот, я переделал своего ***музыкального бота,*** но я столкнулся с тем, что бот не добавляет песни с YouTube в очередь. Сначала я пробовал внутри `if (err) {}` вставить скрипт, но результата этого не привело:(
Проблема заключается в том, что когда я пишу **+add <ссылка>**, бот не записывает id url-ссылки в переменную **`url`**, не пишет в консоль **`[i] Id video: "значение id url"`** и не пишет:

`Добавлено в очередь: *название id url*`

Итак вот фрагмент кода:

````
'add': (msg) => {
    let url = msg.content.split(' ')[1];
    if (url == '' || url === undefined) return msg.channel.send(`Необходимо добавить ссылку на YouTube видео или ID после ${config.prefix}add`);
    yte.getInfo(url, (err, info) => {
        if (err) {
            
        } else {
            var args = msg.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
            args.splice(0, 2);
            console.warn(`[i] Args: [${args}]`);
            var mesg = args.join(" ");
            var options = {
                q: mesg,
                part: 'snippet',
                type: 'video'
            };
            searchYoutube(config.api.youtube_api_key, options, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err + " |-------|-------| " + JSON.stringify(info));
                } else {
                    url = result.items[0].id.videoId;
                    console.warn(`[i] Id video: ${url}`);
                    yte.getInfo(url, (err, info) => {
                        if (err) {
                        } else {
                            if (!queue.hasOwnProperty(msg.guild.id)) queue[msg.guild.id] = {}, queue[msg.guild.id].playing = false, queue[msg.guild.id].songs = [];
                            queue[msg.guild.id].songs.push({url: url, title: info.title, requester: msg.author.username});
                            msg.channel.send("Добавлено в очередь: ```"+info.title+"```");
                            console.warn(`[i] Added ${info+title} in queue`);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
},
````

Comment: Вопрос насчет исправления проблемы - всегда сложный, философский (не имеющий однозначного ответа). А вот _устранить_ проблему, можно практически всегда. Ответ на вопрос: "да".

Comment: Тут требуются (как минимум) подробности о проблеме: в чем она заключается. Например, если возникает ошибка - то какая именно, и на каком выражении; а если ошибки выполнения нет, но код работает некорректно (алгоритмически) - то в чем именно эта некорректность проявляется, и какое выполнение ожидается. И, конечно же, не стоит надеяться что на изъявление "хочу" тут же набегут программисты и будут выполнять работу по отладке/доработке кода...  Что тут можно получить, если не работу: знание. А именно, конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Я ДОБАВИЛ В ЧЁМ ЗАКЛЮЧАЕТСЯ ПРОБЛЕМА!!!